# Cannot find type 'AudioSpectrogram' in scope when extending AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate in Swift

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and have probably a very stupid question, but I want to extend the AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate from AVFoundation.
When I try to extend it I get an error 'cannot find type 'AudioSpectrogram' in scope'.
This is very strange to me because I want to create a new class/type/extension called AudioSpectrogram. I read some info about extensions in Swift but seems I miss some basic info.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

extension AudioSpectrogram: AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
```

Comment: This was copied from the AudioSpectrogram example from Apple. I don't know how this could work but I noticed that on all the code samples of extensions they never change the class/type name. So indeed if I remove 'AudioSpectrogram: ' from the code it compiles. But I get errors later on in the code which might be related. I am trying to make this apple AV example work without the graphics and detect a sound signal of a specific frequency with the  Iphone microphone. I think they use extension, because the AVCapture..Delegate is closed source code , instead of using class inherantance.